# C# SocketException was unhandled

Tags: c#, visual-studio, socketexception

I just went through a YouTube tutorial on tcpip servers and clients and was using the code from it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXFso7xSSWk both part 1 and part 2. I have redone the code twice and have made sure that everything is the same. Whenever I run the server I get the error "SocketException was unhandled" at the line '`tcpListener.Start();`' in the following method.

```
private void TcpServerRun()
        {
            TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5004);
            tcpListener.Start();
            updateUI("Listening");
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                updateUI("Connected");
                Thread tcpHandlerThread = new Thread (new ParameterizedThreadStart(tcpHandler));
                tcpHandlerThread.Start(client);
            }
        }
```

I also get the same error when I run the client, but it is at the line '`client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("10.3.29.252"), 5004);`' in the following method:

```
private void ConnectAsClient()
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("10.3.29.252"), 5004);
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            string s = "Hello from client";
            byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
            stream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
            updateUI("Message send");
            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
```

Any and all help is much appreciated. I am pretty new to coding and very new to c# so I am sorry for anything that maybe unclear.

Here is the entire code for the server:

```
namespace TcpServerTutorial
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void bStartServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread tcpServerRunThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TcpServerRun));
            tcpServerRunThread.Start();
            TcpServerRun();
        }

        private void TcpServerRun()
        {
            TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5004);
            tcpListener.Start();
            updateUI("Listening");
            TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                updateUI("Connected");
                Thread tcpHandlerThread = new Thread (new ParameterizedThreadStart(tcpHandler));
                tcpHandlerThread.Start(client);
            }


        }

        private void tcpHandler(object client)
        {
            TcpClient mClient = (TcpClient)client;
            NetworkStream stream = mClient.GetStream();
            byte[] message = new byte[1024];
            stream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
            updateUI("New Message = " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message));
            stream.Close();
            mClient.Close();
        }

        private void updateUI(string s)
        {
            Func<int> del = delegate()
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(s + System.Environment.NewLine);
                return 0;
            };
            Invoke(del);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: first thought is that address is not reachable. if you do a try catch and check the inner exception you might get more information.

Comment: SocketException.ErrorCode should give you a bit more specific detail on the kind of error you're getting. Any chance the dev machine you're using has a firewall blocking unexpected outbound connections?

Comment: when I put 'tcpListener.Start();' in a try catch it seems to pass that point, but then I get an "invalid operation exception" at 'TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();'

Comment: @DavidW I have tried turning off my firewall but it still gives the exception.

Comment: The additional information was: 'Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.' but I don't know what else could be running on that port or how to check. 5004 is usually free.

Comment: Sounds crazy, but it almost sounds like, in either case, your startup code is executing twice inadvertently. Can you post more of your code?

Comment: @DavidW I added the code to the question. Like I had mention I got this code from youtube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bingo.Look at this chunk of code:

```
    private void bStartServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Called once when the thread starts
        Thread tcpServerRunThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(TcpServerRun));
        tcpServerRunThread.Start();
        // Called again here
        TcpServerRun();
    }
```

The `TCPServerRun()` method is being called twice: once when your thread starts, and then again via the explicit call right after you start the thread (or even possibly in reverse order). That's the call where the `SocketException` occurs, because the server has already started. Remove the second reference and your problem should be resolved; look for a similar situation on your client.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to have helped.